# Interesting call to main method

Tags: java

I was around Wikipedia reading about a programming language called ['D'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29), it is the first time I read about it.

It was curious to me that the syntax looks very similar to Java. 
But most interesting was when I saw their main method uses char[][].

I opened up Eclipse and I tried this:

```
public static void main(char [][] args){
}
```

I was surprised when I saw it compiled with no syntax errors, but I did not understand why.
Can someone explain to me why this call to the main method can compile in Java?

Comment: Actually a String is a array of chars, so an array of an array of chars is a string array. You can define an alias in D: alias char[] string;, so it will be string[] in your main method, which is actually char[][]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As what you have written is valid Java syntax (static void method with name main and as argument a two dimensional char array) it will compile. The problem however is, that this main method will not work as entry point to a Java program, as this has to have the signature:`public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: I see. I thought there was some other alternative. I think since JSE6 there are this new variables called varargs, that can also do something similar. main(String... args), i think that also can compile but not run.

Answer (score 0):

dcn, is correct it is a valid method named main.  But can't be used to start a Java app.

To expand further, there is some flexibility in the signature:

You can use any variable name, not just `args`:

```
public static void main(String[] whateverNameYouWant) {

}
```

The variable must be an array of Strings, but you can declare that in any valid Java syntax, like so:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

}
```

As, Michael Krussel, points out, you can also use varargs:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

}
```

Comment: you can also use varargs main(String... args)